# I am trying to get the difference of measure values in DAX but getting 0

Tags: powerbi, dax, subtraction

I will like to get the difference between two measure values using DAX

AADPMAU_Increase = [AADPMAU_End] - [AADPMAU_Start]

But when I do the subtraction, I am getting 0

I have tried different things, but nothing is working

The two values are **start** and **end** values that are set by date selector filters. It appears that the calculation is always treating both as equal therefore returning 0

---

`AADPMAU_Start = CALCULATE(AADPTable[AADPMAU_Sum],FILTER(DimDate,DimDate[StartDate] = DimDate[StartDate]))`

`AADPMAU_End = CALCULATE(AADPTable[AADPMAU_Sum],FILTER(DimDate,DimDate[EndDate] = DimDate[EndDate]))`

```
AADPMAU Increase = 
var at_end = AADPTable[AADPMAU_End]
var at_start = AADPTable[AADPMAU_Start]
return at_end - at_start
```

[image]

Comment: Look again at the conditions you are passing to `FILTER`. What is `DimDate[StartDate] = DimDate[StartDate]` supposed to do? The two expressions either side of the equals sign are identical. Did you intend one of them to be the *minimum value* of `DimDate[StartDate]` within the current filter context, perhaps?

Comment: The purpose is to select dates from the dropdowns. In this case the dropdowns coming from the DimDate table and displaying values "StartDate" in one dropdown and "EndDate" in the other. This way, one can select "StartDate" and "EndDate" yielding the corresponding values

Comment: Precisely my point. So you should be using something like `DimDate[StartDate]=MIN(DimDate[StartDate])`. Also, you'll almost certainly need to apply an `ALL` (or related function) to the *DimDate* table prior to applying the `FILTER` condition, i.e. `CALCULATE(AADPTable[AADPMAU_Sum],FILTER(ALL(DimDate),DimDate[StartDate]=MIN(DimDate[StartDate])))`

Comment: With the suggesting changes, I am now seeing something other than 0 (which is a great improvement, thank you). But I must still be missing something, because I am seeing the difference not matching what is expected.

Comment: FOR START DATE: CALCULATE(AADPTable[AADPMAU_Sum],FILTER(ALL(DimDate),DimDate[StartDate]=MIN(DimDate[StartDate])))

Comment: FOR END DATE: CALCULATE(AADPTable[AADPMAU_Sum],FILTER(ALL(DimDate),DimDate[StartDate]=MAX(DimDate[StartDate])))

Comment: I see a difference of 1242 (for a StartDate and enddate values of 1551 and 2169, restpectively)

Comment: Why are you referencing `DimDate[StartDate]` in your formula for END DATE? Shouldn't that be referencing `DimDate[EndDate]`?